Axios connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 on Docker
I am running a Node.js app on a Docker container with nginx on my local machine. I am using Axios to make a POST request to APIs which are in different containers but on the same localhost machine. It all works in development without Docker container but as soon as I move it into a container I get errors from Axios:
AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
port: 80,
address: '127.0.0.1',
syscall: 'connect',
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
baseURL: 'http://localhost',
method: 'post',
url: '/microservice/email/api/send',
data: {some data here}

I don't understand why I am getting that error. I get the same error if I try to access a different API endpoint in a separate container where nginx does a proxy_pass to connect to a different localhost port e.g. http://localhost:4040 for the email API.
The nginx configuration is basically:
upstream microservice_email {
    server localhost:4040;
}

server {
gzip on;
gzip_static on;
gunzip on;
gzip_types
.... (removed for brevity but all MIME types here);

client_max_body_size 5000M;

        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  localhost;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # main app running on 8080 and exposed in Docker on that port
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

location /microservice/email/ {
    proxy_pass http://microservice_email/;
    proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

I don't get any such errors using the same nginx configuartion and making POST or whatever REST requests to an endpoint using a rest client like Postman e.g.:
POST http://localhost/microservice/email/api/send
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "From": "volumeone@xxx.xxx",
   "To": "somebody@example.com",
   "Subject": "Congratulations on a working email",
   "Text": "A test email"
}

Running the above works fine and the email is sent. But when done from the main app container using Axios, it never connects because of the AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 error.
Just for testing, I tried doing a rest client request directly to the IP 1270.0.1 and it also fails:
POST http://127.0.0.1/microservice/email/api/send
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "From": "volumeone@xxx.xxx",
   "To": "somebody@example.com",
   "Subject": "This doesn't work",
   "Text": "A test email is never sent"
}

It instead returns this error:

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:80
[/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information


Can you elaborate on your setup, please? The Node container is making requests to itself? If so, why is the Nginx information relevant?

@HansKilian I think its better to ignore the self-requests. The issue is sending a request to another container. It is some problem with the way Docker networking works but I can't work it out. Why does http://localhost/api_endpoint work but http://127.0.01/api_endpoint not work?

I still don't have a clear picture of your setup. But one thing I notice is that you have server_name  localhost; in your Nginx config. That means that there has to be a Host: localhost header in the request. You can't use the server_name directive if you want to call using the IP address (and no Host header).

@HansKilian I dont know why but axios makes requests to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I know they're the same thing but nginx doesn't seem to like the IP I think. The setup is just Docker on Windows, running two containers. One is the main app and the other is an Email service running on a different port. I just want to send POST requests from the main app to the email service to send an email. I am testing it on my local machine. Nginx is there to proxy calls from the main app microservice/emailer/api-endpoint to the Email container at localhost:4040/api-endpoint

Try removing the server_name directive. Then Nginx will accept all requests, with or without Host headers.

You have localhost in this question in several places, but it's very context-specific.  The Nginx container, the email container, and the system running the end user's browser each separately believe they are independently localhost.  So for example, it looks like you're trying to tell the Nginx container to proxy requests to itself ("localhost") on a different port, which seems unlikely to succeed.

@HansKilian thank you but it didn't fix it. It still refuses connection on http://127.0.0.1/ but allows it on http://localhost/. I have even gone into the hosts file in Windows and ensured that 127.0.0.1 localhost mapping is there.

@DavidMaze Well yes because the main app is running on localhost:8080 and the email service is on locahost:4040. So I need nginx to divert requests to the appropriate place e.g. a request to http://localhost/microservice/email/endpoint map to http://localhost:4040/endpoint and it works when using localhost as a string. If it use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost string then it fails.

localhost means something different in each of the main app, the email service, the host system, and the system running the end user's browser.  127.0.0.1 has the exact same context-specific meaning.

@DavidMaze Well I'm truly stumped because axios insists on using 127.0.0.1 even thought the baseURL is localhost and not an IP.
